# Is there any documentation that tells how to use design automation API for Revit linked files

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

Looking for documentation that helps using design automation API with Linked files.
I was able to run the design automation API with Single Revit model file. Now I want to try Revit model file that has multiple linked file. I was looking at Revit documentation https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/ which only talks about single Revit file. Can i get sample code on how to create app bundle, create activities and submit workitem with Revit file thats linked to multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

See several examples on how to send a package containing host and link models (relative path) in the [Task 7 – Submit a Workitem](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/step7-post-workitem/) documentation.

There is also a code sample [forge-countdeletewalls-revit](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-countdeletewalls-revit) that shows how to traverse all linked models to count doors, walls, windows and floors.

Comment: If i understand it correctly, when i'm at this https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/revit/step6-prepare-cloud-storage/#step-3-upload-a-file-to-the-signed-url, I need to upload a zip file (that has all models and linked models) instead of single RVT file?

Comment: Here also is a blog post that can help - https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/make-composite-revit-design-work-design-automation-api-revit